# Colorado Plant/Weed Identification Thistle thing with purple flowers

Tags: identification

Can anyone help me identify this plant?  It is located in the foothills of Colorado.

[image]

and a younger version:
[image]

Have not had any luck that past few days online and would appreciate any shared knowledge!

Comment: It's similar enough to [_Liatris spicata_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liatris_spicata) (which I grow) that it might be another species of [_Liatris_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liatris).

Comment: Looks promising from the pictures on the wiki page. You should post a full answer so you can get the rep you deserve!

Comment: I'm trying to get a better id.  _L. punctata_ and _L. pycnostachya_ look promising... Bear with me

Comment: I haven't been able to get a positive identification, so I'll leave it for someone who knows what they're talking about. :)

Comment: Niall: its a Liatris, most likely spicata, so post your ID!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [*Liatris*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liatris), most likely [*Liatris spicata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liatris_spicata) (commonly known as Blazing Star) which is widely grown as a garden flower in the USA.  Another possibility is [*L. punctata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liatris_punctata) which is [native to Colorado](http://plants.usda.gov/java/profile?symbol=LIPU).

*L. spicata* is easily identified by their long flower spikes composed of hundreds of smaller feathery florets in pink, magenta or purple.   They also have long narrow leaves arranged radially around the stem.  They're perennials, growing from a corm, so you can look forward to seeing them again in future years.

Comment: and in good conditions where they are not dead headed they verge on being weedy